# SQL query to obtain a count of how many items have each possible value for a given column

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by, strftime

Okay, so I have a (SQLite) table called log wherein one column (time) is a Unix epoch timestamp (the other columns are irrelevant for my purposes). These are timestamped log entries.

I am trying to get a count of how many items are logged per hour (all-time -- I don't care to do it only for a given day or whatever; I'm trying to get an idea of activity density throughout the *average* day). I have been successful in basically binning these into hours with the query `SELECT STRFTIME('%H', DATETIME(time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) FROM log;`, which then gives me just a huge list of numbers 0-23 which I can run through `uniq -c` to get a count of events per hour.

However (more out of stubbornness than any practical need, I admit), I want to do this counting step in SQL. My brain got me as far as knowing I'd prrroooobably have to do some kind of self-join to get only the unique values for the generated hours column, but that's where it crapped out D: Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%H', DATETIME(time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')), 
COUNT(anotherField)
FROM log
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%H', DATETIME(time, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));
```

Note: I haven't worked with SQLite. However, it supports `GROUP BY` and hence, this should work.

Comment: +1: GROUP BY is required in standard SQL, but [SQLite (like MySQL) does support hidden columns](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: Oh man, I forgot all about GROUP BY, shows how rusty I am. This query might be just a little slow but for what I'm dealing with it's really just fine. By the way, it's probably better to SELECT STRFTIME(...) AS hour [...] GROUP BY hour.

Comment: @tgies: I don't know if SQLite supports `GROUP BY hour` kind of syntax because I haven't worked with it. Other DBs (such as SQL Server) don't support column alias in group by, IIRC.

Comment: SQLite does support grouping by alias. It's the best way not to make a huge accident. Come to think of it, Oracle and MySQL do too, so perhaps it is SQL Server which stands out by not supporting it?

Answer (score 1):

why use COUNT(anotherField)?

Use `SELECT [your expression], COUNT(*) FROM log GROUP BY [your expression]`